# In Grimm how exactly was Juliette resurrected as Eve?

Tags: grimm

A Secret Society by the name of Hadrian's Wall is mentioned in that they took Juliette's corpse after Trubel put an arrow through her body, but there is no explanation as to how they resurrected her.

Comment: Wiki suggests that she didn't actually die; https://grimm.fandom.com/wiki/Eve#Near_Death_and_Starting_Over

Comment: Duplicate of: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/158949/how-did-juliette-become-eve?rq=1  ???

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found anything authoritative, such as a line from the script, but in the wikis, it's consistently indicated that she did not die in "Cry Havoc", and when her injured body was retrieved by Hadrian's Wall, they nursed her back to health before or during psychologically breaking her to make her Eve.